# Change kendo ui mvc grid filter menu position to left side of the header text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using **kendo grid** with detail template in my MVC project. By default filter menu button is right align in the header part of grid. My requirement is to show this filter button in the left side of the header. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below CSS

```css
.k-header>.k-grid-filter{
   float:left!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. Now the filter menu is coming on left side. But, some of header text is getting truncated. Is there any way to get full header text in my scenario ?

Comment: You mean that you have empty space in header text but still it is getting header text truncated or header text doesn't have enough space to fit the text?

Comment: I had the same condition of the header text getting overwritten slightly by the icon.  I solved it by also adding to above CSS `margin-right: 0px;`